# How can I change a public variable in the Inspector?

Tags: c#, variables, unity-game-engine, unityscript, unity3d-editor

I have a game object. In the "Inspector" of the game object there are some scripts. Now I want to change a public variable that is attached to the script. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
GameObject.Find("Wanderer").GetComponent<SteerForTeether>().TetherPosition = "whatever";
```

That should do it I suppose

Comment: Note that if the `TestScript` is attached to "Wanderer", you wouldn't need to use `GameObject.Find()`.

Comment: @Aodai Irshed: Not working. Gameobject.Find("Wanderer").GetComponent().TetherPosition. Can't find TetherPosition

Comment: No, I wrote it right. This is not the problem. When I try to type "Tether...", nothing is showed. Here: GameObject st = GameObject.GetComponent().XXX;

Comment: You should do it like I wrote it getcomponeny<scriptname>().variable

Comment: Not working: GameObject.GetComponent(<SteerForTether>()).TetherPosition = new Vector3 (0,0,0);

Comment: Don't add a '(' before just like I wrote it .. GetComponent<scriptname>().whatever

Comment: Also does not work: GameObject.GetComponent<SteerForTether>().TetherPosition = new Vector3 (0,0,0); -> Error: The name 'SteerForTether' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Well sure it won't it's either you use GameObject.find("objectname") before get component so it would be like this GameObject.Find("objectname").GetComponent<scriptname>().var or you just write GetComponent<scriptname>().var

Comment: Now it's woking. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

A script attached to an object is a [**Component**](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.html) of the object. To access to a component, you need to call [`GetComponent<TYPE>()`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html) method from the game object. The type of the component would be same as the name of the script you are trying to reach.

Here's an example:

```
GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<PlayerController>().KillPlayer();
```

The name of the script, in this case, is `PlayerController.cs`. `KillPlayer()` is a public method defined in this script.